# How to compute a sweeping cutoff filter in python?

Tags: filters, python

I would like to compute a sweeping cutoff filter.
I wish to use SciPy.
I sliced my wave into x samples slices, in order to apply a different cutoff to each such created "frame".
The problem is that the filter, when applied to a slice filters the "clic" at the start of the slice, which creates an artefact for regathered result.
I searched stackexchange all over for sweeping filters questions and found nothing.
Any Idea on how to get a smooth sweeping without clic?

```
    #for filter
    from scipy.signal import butter, buttord, lfilter, freqz
    from scipy.signal import freqs

    def truncate_if_outside(data, bitwidth):
        if bitwidth==2:
            max_sample_value=32767
            min_sample_value=-32767
        else:
            print "Only 16 bit accepted by truncate_if_outside function"
    

        for i in range(len(data)):  
            if data[i]>max_sample_value:
                data[i]=max_sample_value;
            if data[i]<min_sample_value:
                data[i]=min_sample_value;
            if math.isnan(data[i]):
                data[i]=0
            data[i]=int(data[i])
            if math.isnan(data[i]):
                data[i]=0
        return data


    def lowpass_filter(integer_data, sample_framerate, sample_bitwidth,threshold):#works with cutoff from 400 and higher

        def butter_lowpass(cutOff, fs, order):
    
            nyq = 0.5 * fs
            normalCutoff = cutOff / nyq
            b, a = butter(order, normalCutoff, btype='low', analog = False)
            return b, a
    
        def butter_lowpass_filter(data, cutOff, fs, order):
            b, a = butter_lowpass(cutOff, fs, order=order)
            y = lfilter(b, a, data)
            return y
    
        result=butter_lowpass_filter(integer_data, threshold, sample_framerate, order=4)#what is order?
        result=truncate_if_outside(result, sample_bitwidth)
        return result

    def sweep_filter(integer_data, start_freq, end_freq, sample_framerate, sample_bitwidth, slice_width):
        num_slice= int(len(integer_data)/ float(slice_width))
        print "nombre de tranche dans cette durée :",num_slice
        new_data=[]
        diff_cutoff=end_freq-start_freq
        for i in range(num_slice):
            current_cutoff=start_freq+((i/float(num_slice))*diff_cutoff)
            print "cutoff",current_cutoff
            print "start:",i*slice_width
            offset_first_sample=(i*slice_width)-1
            offset_last_sample=((i*slice_width)+slice_width)-1

            slice_data=integer_data[offset_first_sample:offset_last_sample]
            slice_data=lowpass_filter(slice_data, sample_framerate, sample_bitwidth, current_cutoff)
            for j in range(len(slice_data)):
                new_data.append(slice_data[j])
        return new_data
```

[image: Sweep clic signal image]

The here filtered signal is a "smoothed noise" which means a random numbers smoothed with exponential curves. There should be no gap in it.

Answer (score 1):

To create a smooth sweeping filter or envelope filter, you can process as in video by "frame". You plan a 30% overlap of each frame with a crossfade.
You need to generate two tracks and mix them together to do that.

Comment: or you can gradually adjust the coefficients, a little with each sample.

Comment: finally 100% overlap works better

Comment: robert: is it possible to filter with a frame of one sample? are you sure? it seems bizarre to me as to detect a frequency there need to be a wave!